# Why these two spaces are homotopically equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let us define $X=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: (x-1)^2+y^2=1 \} \cup \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: (x+1)^2+y^2=1 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $Y=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: (x-2)^2+y^2=1 \} \cup \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: (x+2)^2+y^2=1 \} \cup \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y=0, -1 \leq x \leq 1\}$.

I know that $\pi_1(X,(0,0))=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}=\pi_1(Y,(0,0))$ and that there is an identification $\pi : Y \to X$ which identificate $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y=0, -1 \leq x \leq 1\}$ into a point. But how can we construct an homotopic equivalence?

I understand that the idea is to shorten the line $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y=0, -1 \leq x \leq 1\}$ gradually but I would like to answer formally.

I found other questions about this problem but I would like to know if there is a way not using cell attachements. I am searching for explicit equivalent map.

Comment: They are deformation retracts of the same space, where that space is a larger 3-d object that contains $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @Kevin.S Could you please add more details?

Comment: Consider $B=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2+z^2=9\}\setminus\{(-3/2,0,0),(3/2,0,0)\}$, there is a deformation retraction to $X$ by expanding the two holes to two sphere centered at $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$, respectively, and collapse other parts to the two spheres. $Y$ is similar but we have to deform the middle part to a line segment.

Comment: @Kevin.S Could you please post it as an answer expliciting the deformation retracts and the expansion you quoted?

Comment: @Kevin.S I will edit it.

Comment: Oh, I realized that I misread the question, I thought that everything is in dimension 3...sorry, now I see that everything is in dimension two....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $B=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2\le9\}\setminus\{(-2/3,0),(2/3,0)\}$, then we construct two deformation retractions. Well, maybe I missed something but this result is quite complicated since I used the straight line homotopy. (there's no other good way probably)

1. we construct a deformation retraction $F:B\times I\to Y$:
   $$
   F((x,y),t)=
   \begin{cases}
   (x,(1-y)t+y) & -2/3\le x\le2/3\\
   (x,t\sqrt{1-(x+2)^2}+(1-t)y)  & (x+2)^2+y^2\ge1,-3\le x\le-1\\
   (x,t\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}+(1-t)y) & (x-2)^2+y^2\ge1,1\le x\le3\\
   (ta_x+(1-t)x,ta_y+(1-t)y) & \text{ otherwise}
   \end{cases}
   $$
   where the 4th branch deals with points bounded by the two circles, so $a_x$ is the targeted point to which $x$-coordinate needs to be sent, similarly, $a_y$ represents one to which $y$-coordinate ought to be sent, where $(a_x,a_y)$ must be on one of the circles. Both of which can be solved using $(x\pm2)^2+(kx\pm3/2x)^2=1$ where $k$ is the slope.
2. For $H:B\times I\to X$ we define two steps:

1) Define $G:B\times I\to X'$:
$$G((x,y),t)=
\begin{cases}
(x,y) & x^2+y^2\le4\\
t\frac{2(x,y)}{||(x,y)||}+(1-t)(x,y) & \text{ otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$
2) Define $K:X'\times I\to X$:
$$H((x,y),t)=
\begin{cases}
(x,t\sqrt{1-(x+1)^2}+(1-t)y) & (x+1)^2+y^2\ge1,-2\le x\le0\\
(x,t\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}+(1-t)y) & (x-1)^2+y^2\ge1,0\le x\le2\\
(ta_x'+(1-t)x,ta_y'+(1-t)y) & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where $ta_x'$ and $ta_y'$ can be obtained using a similar way as what we did in 1. Here $H=K\circ G$. Here, $G$ squeez the initial punctured disk and then $K$ uses straight line homotopy to map all points to the wedge circles.

---

I didn't solve for every constant in the construction (sorry for that) because we should avoid too much unnecessary calculation especially when we try to prove the existence, but I did a lot since you asked for a relatively explicit map. Actually, the following picture in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* should be able to answer your question.

> [image]

---

Besides, the fundamental groups in your post are still incorrect. We proved that $X\simeq Y$ because they're deformation retracts of the same space. and $X\cong S^1\vee S^1\implies \pi_1(X,(0,0))\approx\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}$ by Seifert-Van Kampen's Thm. So $\pi_1(X)\approx\pi_1(Y)\approx\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}$ by homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I see it.

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini You're welcome, I'm glad to help.